# Can a Sharepoint 2010 List calendar migrate to an Office365 Room Resource?

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-calendar

We have a really old 2010 list that was setup like a conference room calendar. I want to setup an Office365 Room Resource and am hoping someone knows how to migrate the data over from the list to the Resource. Exporting the list to .stp is possible, and exporting to Excel is possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In office 2010, in the calendar view select the connect to Outlook option. Once you go through the steps of connecting in Outlook, select the calendar in your Outlook app. You may have to deselect your own calendar. Then click on the file tab, and save calendar as the prompted .ics file.

I want to add how I had to import it also. In Office365 online I went to my Calendar or Outlook, selected my photo to open additional options and selected open another mailbox. Put in the email of the existing resource and opened. This is where it is oddly setup. There is not an obvious place on the page to select calendar. There is a tiny little agenda icon under filter that when clicked opens an option to go to calendar. Once there add calendar from tab, select from file. Easy Peasy Lemon Squeezy.